# Cannot install pyodbc using pip for python 3.9 (32-bit)

Tags: python, windows, pip, pyodbc

I have installed pyodbc in python 3.9 64-bit scripts, and am attempting to install the pyodbc on python 3.9 32 bit, but when I follow the same steps as I did before I get the Error

'C:\Users\ICAPP02\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\Scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I am copying the exact path from the scripts folder for my 32 to the command prompt.

Don't know what else to try, already tried modifying python and checking the environment variable box.

Comment: Are you trying to do `cd C:\Users\ICAPP02\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\Scripts` from a command prompt?

Comment: Yes, from what I've found pyodbc is installed via the command prompt.

Comment: Well, if that `cd` command fails then either 32-bit Python is not actually installed or it isn't where you think it is. Launch 32-bit IDLE, then do `import os` followed by `os.getcwd()`. That should show you the base folder of the Python install.

Comment: This helped, I got it installed finally!